# How do I filter an intent based on cropping ability on android?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to allow the user to select a photo and crop the image. This is working most of the time. The problem  I am having is that the App Chooser is showing apps that do not have cropping abilities.

[image]
For example this is the App Chooser that comes up. However only the "Gallery" has the ability to crop.

So I need a way to filter the other three apps. Otherwise my users will get confused and angry.

Here is the code I am using currently:

```
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 50);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 68);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 50);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 68);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_picture)), SELECT_IMAGE);
        } else {
            //Show error
        }
```

Comment: see this: 
http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However only the "Gallery" has the ability to crop.

Only on some devices. There is no requirement, AFAIK, for a gallery app to offer some sort of cropping capability.

> So I need a way to filter the other three apps

No, you need to realize that there is no cropping ability that is officially part of Android. Then, you need to implement cropping inside of your app. This is covered in greater detail [in a blog post of mine](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) that baronS mentioned in a comment.

Comment: I read your blog before I posted my question. I looking for a way to detect the presence of a cropping app. If none is found I can fall back to a different behavior.

Comment: @theJosh: There is no way for you to determine if an `ACTION_PICK` `Intent` responder will offer cropping, nor a way to filter `startActivity()` so that only crop-capable `ACTION_PICK` implementations will be used.